# Передача параметров в Activity Result Launcher

Tags: java, android, activity

У меня есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую я должен получить изображение из хранилища устройства, а затем передать его и еще несколько параметров в `RecyclerView adapter`.
Я пробую сначала запускать `activity result launcher` с `putExtra`, а в нём, когда изображение взято (`result_ok`), отправить его и `extras` в `RecyclerView adapter`. Однако, `extras` передаются только дефолтные, а значит, параметры не передались. Что я делаю не так?

P.S.: было бы здорово дождаться результата (изображения) от вызванного `Intent`, а уже потом внутри `void createPostItem(int type, int position)` продолжать работать с данными, но как я понял, такое невозможно, и нужно работать внутри `activity result launcher`.

```
    private void createPostItem(int type, int position) {
                    updatePermissions();
    
                    if (isReadPermissionGranted && isWritePermissionGranted) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        intent.putExtra("type", type); // не передался
                        intent.putExtra("position", position); // не передался
    
                        loadImageLauncher.launch(intent);
                    }
   }
    
   private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> loadImageLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null) {
                            Uri imageUri = result.getData().getData();
                            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromUri(imageUri);
                            Intent intent = result.getData();
    
                            if (intent != null) {
                                int type = intent.getIntExtra("type", 3); // всегда 3
                                int position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 9); // всегда 9
    
                                String path = saveImageToInternalStorage(bitmap, "" + position);
    
                                // передача в adapter
                                if (adapter.createPostItem(type, position, path)) {
                                    setContentToPreferences();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: значения не передаются потому что `Intent intent = result.getData();` уже отличается от того который вы создавали ранее, ищите другие варианты передачи параметров

Comment: @Tiarait Спасибо за объяснение! Пока использовал глобальные переменные, и всё удалось передать. Ищу решение получше :)